# Eclipse CDT - "Invalid arguments" when using template defaults

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am getting a weird error with the following code:

```
template<class T, size_t Size = sizeof(T)>
class foobar {
};

template<class T>
void foo(foobar<T> param1) {
    // Do something
}

void bar() {
    foobar<int> obj;

    foo(obj);
}
```

The error occurs at the line `foo(obj);` and is:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void foo(foobar<#0,unsigned int16 0 #0>)
'
```

The code itself compiles fine however. I have no idea how to fix it.

[Eclipse giving me Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void * memset(void *, int, ?) ' though I know the args are good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021594/eclipse-giving-me-invalid-arguments-candidates-are-void-memsetvoid-int) did not fix it, so this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Tried `template<class T, size_t Size = sizeof(T)>` already?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes. No just a slightly different error, representing the different type.

Comment: _"The code itself compiles fine however."_ What do you mean _code itself_? Templates are compiled as they are instantiated.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mean this code compiles without problems.

Comment: So you're asking about a Eclipse CDT intellisense warning?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes. Exactly.

Comment: Intellisense isn't very reliable about that, especially not with templates. Recompiling/reindexing sometimes helps.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I already tried that. No difference.

Comment: The c++ parser used with the intellisense feature isn't necessarily the same as used with your actual toolchain.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know that too. The problem is just that I have around 20 of these errors and they're annoying at least. (Not to mention wrong)

Comment: Well, these arent really wrong. Because the correct form should be `template<class T, size_t Size = sizeof(T)>` as mentioned.

Comment: tell eclipse to ignore them, most IDEs fail when it comes to templates

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm actually using size_t in my actual code. But decided to not use it in this minimal example since it doesn't compile without a header. I'll change it for clarifcation.

Comment: @ZivS how? Just deleting them will simply recreate them

Comment: I guess here: Project Settings -> C/C++ General -> Code Analysis
But I'm not using eclipse so I don't know for sure

Comment: @ZivS sadly I can only turn the whole error off, which is a bit bothersome since it mean I won't get warned when actually using wrong arguments. But it's ok I guess. Thank you

Comment: intellisense is Visual Studio. Eclipse CDT calls pretty much the same thing CODAN. Unlikely that anyone is going to sue a helpsite over misuse of a trademarked term, but the knowing the right terminology may help websearches.

Comment: Yeah. That's repeatable. May be worth a bug report.

Comment: There is active work on the C++ code base in CDT at the moment, what I recommend is submit your reproducible test case to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT

Comment: @JonahGraham I will report it.

Comment: I don't see a bug filed on this topic, so I filed one myself: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513430.

Comment: @HighCommander4 thank you for reporting it yourself. I have been very busy the last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in CDT. A [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513430) has been filed to track it, and a [patch](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/92855/) that fixes it has been posted.

**UPDATE**: The bug has now been [fixed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513430#c4). The fix will appear in Eclipse Oxygen.