# Why does Eclipse complain about this use of C++ templates?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, sfinae, c++-templates

In Eclipse, I’m looking at code which is essentially the same as the example posted in the [codereview.SX question *“C++17: Boost.Hana based compile-time plugin registration”*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/192825), just condensed into one file and with the Boost stuff stripped out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class>
struct sfinae_true;

template<unsigned int>
struct registry_hook;

namespace registry {
  template<class Dummy, unsigned int testN>
  constexpr sfinae_true<decltype(registry_hook<testN>{})> test(int);
  template<class Dummy, unsigned int testN>
  constexpr std::false_type test(long);

  template<class Dummy, unsigned int testN = 0>
  constexpr unsigned int get_free_N() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same<decltype(test<Dummy, testN>(0)), std::false_type>::value) {
        return testN;
    } else {
        return get_free_N<Dummy, testN + 1>();
    }
  }
}

struct Dummy1;
template<>
struct registry_hook<registry::get_free_N<Dummy1>()> {
    constexpr static unsigned int my_N = registry::get_free_N<Dummy1>();
};

struct Dummy2;
template<>
struct registry_hook<registry::get_free_N<Dummy2>()> {
    constexpr static unsigned int my_N = registry::get_free_N<Dummy2>();
};


int main() {
    constexpr unsigned int max_N = registry::get_free_N<void>() - 1;
    std::cout << max_N << std::endl;
}
```

This compiles and works fine with both GCC and clang:

```
$ g++     -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cc && ./a.out
1
$ clang++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cc && ./a.out
1
```

However, Eclipse complains about the lines with explicit template specializations, giving the error “Invalid template argument”. The parser log file shows the same, without any more context:

> ```
> Project:               test
> File:                  file:[…]/main.cc
> Language:              GNU C++
> Index Version:         220.0
> Build Configuration:   Default
> Context:               file:[…]/main.cc
>    C++, {}
> Versions in Index:     1
>    C++: {}; 0 macros, 2 includes, 47 names;
>
> Include Search Path (option -I):
>    /usr/include/c++/11
>    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11
>    /usr/include/c++/11/backward
>    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include
>    /usr/local/include
>    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
>    /usr/include
>
> Macro definitions (option -D):
>    […]
>
> Unresolved names:
>    A template id provides illegal arguments for the instantiation: registry_hook in file […]/main.cc:28
>    A template id provides illegal arguments for the instantiation: registry_hook in file […]/main.cc:34
>
> Written on Tue Dec 05 23:01:27 EST 2023
> ```

I don’t see what the problem is supposed to be. Is this just a bug in Eclipse/CDT?

Comment: Program is well-formed. Looks like a bug in Eclipse. [Works](https://godbolt.org/z/3nGnEn4h1) in all compilers.

Comment: [Eclipse CDT - "Invalid arguments" when using template defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586662/eclipse-cdt-invalid-arguments-when-using-template-defaults) and [Eclipse CDT Invalid template arguments on map std::map< std::string, Stock*> &stocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912489/eclipse-cdt-invalid-template-arguments-on-map-stdmap-stdstring-stock-st)

Comment: @user12002570 Those two were both fixed a long time ago, unless you’re using these links to say that bugs in Eclipse CDT are not uncommon?

Comment: @Socob Yes these types of bugs are very common in eclipse cdt. As I said in my deleted answer, the program is well formed and there is nothing wrong with the explicit specializations in your program.