# Eclipse giving me Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: float atanf(float)' even though the arguments are valid

Tags: eclipse, invalid-argument

This is similar to

[Eclipse giving me Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void * memset(void *, int, ?) ' though I know the args are good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021594/eclipse-giving-me-invalid-arguments-candidates-are-void-memsetvoid-int)

This line gives the error

```
float y = atanf(x);
```

The error is

```
Invalid arguments 'Candidates are:float atanf(float)'

I tried
1) enable provider "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings [ Shared ]".
2) clean; reindex; build
3) rewrite code as
   float tan_arg = x;
   float y = atanf(tan_arg);
```

To keep moving forward, I disabled check arguments on that line, but I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: Clearly, the key to this is what argument you are providing, but you haven't shown that.

Comment: I could have cast the argument, and I'll try that option.  But, option 3, I rewrote that line with a float argument.

Comment: The problem is this "x" thing. You've provided no info on what that is, except for its name.

Comment: Option 3 shows tanarg declared as a float and assigned x.  Original line used expression for the atanf argument.  Unfortunately, I had to reflash due to apt-get update fetch error, so code is gone.  And, unfortunately, I followed another github repository recommendation to install ros which is again causing the fetch error, so I have to reflash again.  I'm trying to evaluate Orb Slam 2 on a Xavier.  The expression here was in an Orb Slam 2 example that wouldn't compile.  The author of the Orb Slam 2 repository is in contact due to a separate issue, and I'll inquire about the fetch error.

Comment: And I'll inform him about this atanf error.  The original code didn't compile using make so I was using eclipse as an editor.